# Area co-ordinates are not working in angular ionic

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Can anyone help me to implement a clickable area in ionic? I mentioned the code below. which is totally working fine in normal HTML. but when I place this code to into my ionic project it is not working.[image]

```html
<img src="menfront.png" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area  href="https://www.google.co.in" coords="617,2006,721,2242" shape="rect">
</map>
```

Answer (score 1):

best way to work this is, make this image to svg and define the paths with transparent value. and tag the click operation inside the paths. it will work fine.